# Height and width are set to 0px when embedding Google Maps on Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I am using a theme made by `Start Bootstrap`. (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/)

The portfolio section is implemented as a list of `Bootstrap modal`s.

I tried to insert a Google map on the `modal` body, but it doesn't show on the screen.

My html code for the map is

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
                     .
                     .
                     .
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                                  .
                                  .
                                  .
                        <div class="map" id="map-ubnorth" style="height:300px;width:500px;position:absolute;">abc</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, as you can see below, in my browser, the height and width is set to 0, and displays nothing.

[image]

Interestingly, when I put the map code outside of the modal, on the main page, it displays the map with the specified height and width.

What am I doing wrong? I thought it was a CSS issue at first, but it doesn't seem like so.

Comment: remove the `position:absolute` and then try.

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: Are you sure, Its work for. It will be good if you provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `embed-responsive` instead of `height` and `width` for your map size.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
 <div id="map-ubnorth" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the example: http://a0u.org/map_modal.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire the `resize` event on your map instance when the modal becomes visible:

```
$('#portfolioModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // Assuming your map instance is stored in variable 'map'
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```